# c# for loop exiting after 1 cycle

Tags: c#

In my project I try to loop over values and call a function on them. When debuging Count tells me there are 2 values. My function runs in  a DispatcherTimer

My timer in the constructor:

```
DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(runSync);
dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, syncTime);
dispatcherTimer.Start();
```

My function

```
private void runSync(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //I can see the value of count is 2 when using break points
    List<string> vals = repo.getRemovedAnswers();
    for (int i = 0; i < vals.Count(); i ++ )
    {
        //i do something with the element in my database

        // send back a confirmation that the delete is finished
        repo.setAnswerDeleted(vals.ElementAt(i));
        Console.WriteLine(i + " removed");
        //
    }              
    Console.WriteLine("syncing");

}
```

Function setAnswerDeleted in my repo class, it is a void method so not returning a break or anything.

```
 public List<String> getRemovedAnswers()
 {
    return _answersRemoved;
 }

public void setAnswerDeleted(string uniqueIdAnswer)
{
  _answersRemoved.RemoveAll( item => item == uniqueIdAnswer);

}
```

In the log I can see the loop runs every dispatchtimer cycle and onyl calls the method 1 time, why is the for loop not running 2 times when count == 2?

Comment: Does `getRemovedAnswers()` by any chance `return _answersRemoved;`? Then you're removing elements from the same list you're iterating through.

Comment: @AlexD it is, but does it change the value of vals? its in a different class dosnt it make a copy?

Comment: @SvenB No, it's a reference to the same list.

Comment: If `getRemovedAnswers` returns a `List<string>` "as is", it just returns the object, not a copy.

Comment: Please add the code of _getRemovedAnswers_

Comment: @KyleW so if i understand it right, the value of count is updated after the first loop and thats the reason it only loops 1 time?

Comment: @Sven, basically.  Although count is a function and it will be called each iteration.  This code will run half the iterations you expect it to.

Comment: As expected, you use the same list and removing elements from this list makes your Count call in the for loop going out of synch. You should use the reverse loop approach showed in one of the answers below

Comment: Are you just trying to do `_answersRemoved.Clear()`?

Comment: @JakubLortz In the runSync function i update a database based on the val list values, after the update i confirm to the _answersRemoved that these values have been updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change your code in this way:

```
private void runSync(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //I can see the value of count is 2 when using break points
    List<string> vals = repo.getRemovedAnswers();
    for (int i = vals.Count() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        repo.setAnswerDeleted(vals.ElementAt(i));
        Console.WriteLine(i + " removed");
    //
    }              
    Console.WriteLine("syncing");

}
```

Your for iterate once because you remove the element from the list and the increment your index by one but the elements after delete are previus length - 1, so the next check for vals.Count() return 1 and your index is 1. In this way your index start with 1 and in second step is 0.

Comment: You should explain why you made the change you did

Comment: @pquest You are right, sorry. I hope the explanation is understandable.

Comment: Side note: while this solve the problem it highlights the issue of returning reference to mutable internal list. If `GetRemovedAnswers` method has chance to be used by anyone but original author of the code it may be better to return copy of list.

Comment: This solution assumes that `setAnswerDeleted` doesn't remove more than one element from the list. It's correct only if the list doesn't contain duplicates.

Comment: @JakubLortz Yes it's true. I assume that list didn't contain duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're modifying the list as you're iterating over it, so it is removing the elemnts and the Count() result is going down each loop.  Best practice would be to return a copy of the list, so that you're not modifying it as you go.

```
List<string> getRemovedAnswers()
{
  .. logic
  List<string> previousReturn = ...
  return new List<string>(previousReturn);// Creates new list
}
```

Another good practice is to use a `foreach` loop instead of going by the index.

```
foreach(var element in vals)
{
  repo.setAnswerDeleted(element);
}
```

If you had done this, it would have thrown an exception, saying that the collection was modified while iterating over it.  This would have alerted you to the problem right away.

Comment: As you've said first sample not going to work at all due to the fact `vals` is changed by `setAnswerDeleted` - you probably should put solution first and explanation of wrong approaches later. I personally like "copy" solution much better than hacking iteration to work over collection that is modified during iteration.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I updated it to put the solution at the top.  I agree that counting backwards is just covering the problem (which is what I think you said).